# JoptionPane Gettting Yes Option even I Press Enter On No

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

I am Working with Swing Application. and in one of my application when i put some code on the windowclosing event.

```
try {
    int dialog = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(
      null,
      "are you sure?",
      "Warning",
      JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,
      JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE
    );
    if (dialog == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
        System.out.println("Close system.");
        System.exit(0);
    } else if (dialog == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION) {
       System.out.println("do not Close system.");
    }
} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

and as i give Yes option with space and same way no button on space its working fine. but when i tried to do same things on enter. its taking all time yes option even if i press no option its taking yes and so that window is closed.

so how can i prevent that. and achieve what i want to do?
[image: See this image]

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example).

Comment: okey just min i am giving screen shot :)

Comment: @AndrewThompson see image getting idea now if i focus no and press enter then still its pressing Yes by default. that is the problem

Comment: I didn't ask for a screenshot.  Actually follow the link and *read* about an MCVE.

Comment: i have just wrote some logic into the windowclosing event. and that is only logic what i have show u. there is no code left to show u. what mcve more i can give huh?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is the GUI behaviour of the Enter key versus the Space key. You could use **OK_CANCEL_OPTION**, as OK is more associated with Enter, and might deter using Enter for "Cancel".

Comment: Thank you for ans :) and ya if i am not wrong that u mean to say that it depends on the look and fill ?

Comment: I tried it with and without Nimbus on Windows to no avail. I am afraid Enter is hardwired to the default button.

Comment: okey Brother i got it. and ya i can not say that i can not be true. because what u saying its making sense logically. :) is there any way that i can prevent it?

Comment: Like registering a global KeyListener and switching Enter with Space? A long shot, but you might try - as JOptionPane is modal it might work satisfactory.

Comment: look i have edited your ans :) its working